# Error message when trying to open newly downloaded mySQL

Tags: mysql, command-line, localhost, macos-high-sierra

I am running MacOS High Sierra version 10.13.2 on a MacBook Air (mid 2011).

I am trying to set up a local development environment through the command-line and I have already gone through some steps to the following point:
After downloading mySQL, I am and trying to initialize it through the command line for my localhost. I went then through the commands:

> sudo mkdir /var/mysql

Followed by

> sudo ln -s /tmp/mysql.sock /var/mysql/mysql.sock

Then went to my system preferences  to start mySQL but I am encountering this error message and mySQL is not opening as a result: "Could not load MySQL preference pane."

Any help around this would be much appreciated friends! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

An easier way to install (certain) apps in MacOS is to use [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/). There is a full step-by-step guide available [here](https://gist.github.com/nrollr/3f57fc15ded7dddddcc4e82fe137b58e). A short version:

> - Install Homebrew: `/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"`
> - Install MySQL: `brew install mysql`
> - Install services: `brew tap homebrew/services`
> - Set MySQL to autostart: `brew services start mysql`